# playing and switching between audio files using jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

I am trying to create a sort of radio switchboard.
For this i used a piece of javascript i found to switch between different radio stations in such a way that when i clicked on another radio, the previous one stopped. 
This worked for a while, but i couldn't find a way to have the radio re buffer the moment i clicked it.

Wanting tho change the code to jquery, i keep running into dead ends, and i can not get my code to work.
I would like to create it in such a way that you can switch between radio stations, but when you switch back, it reloads that specific audio file so that you keep the feeling of a "live" stream going.

An example of the html code:

```
<!-- row -->
<div class="row">
    <!-- col  onClick="EvalSound('R538'); return false;" -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="stationcontainer"/>
        <div class="Studio">Radio 538</div>
        <div class="Player">
            <audio id="R538">
                <source src="http://vip-icecast.538.lw.triple-it.nl:80/WEB16_MP3" type="audio/mp3">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- col  onClick="EvalSound('Qmusic'); return false;" -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="stationcontainer"/>
        <div class="Studio">Q Music</div>
        <div class="Player">
            <audio id="Qmusic">
                <source src="http://icecast-qmusic.cdp.triple-it.nl:80/Qmusic_be_live_96.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- col  onClick="EvalSound('TopRadio'); return false;" -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="stationcontainer"/>
        <div class="Studio">Top Radio</div>
        <div class="Player">
            <audio id="TopRadio">
                <source src="http://lb.topradio.be/topradio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The Javascript i used to use:

```
    //switch between radio stations
    var currentPlayer;

    function EvalSound(soundobj) {


        //turn off when selecting another player
        var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);

        if (currentPlayer && currentPlayer != thissound) {
            currentPlayer.pause();
        }
        if (thissound.paused) 
            thissound.play();

        else thissound.pause();

        thissound.currentTime = 0;
        currentPlayer = thissound;
    }
```

and a test jquery i am trying to get started
        //when ready
        $(function () {

```
        //test
        $('.stationcontainer').click(function () {

            //get current audio id
            var thissound = $(this).find('id');

            thissound.play();

        });

    });
```

Comment: thissound[0].play();

Comment: Are you trying to explain that when you change sources, you want the new source to start at the place it was originally at? Or that if the page has been open for 1 minute, then the new source should start at 01:00? A clearerr explanation of your goal would help a lot here

Comment: Rory, The second one. So if you are listening to another station for half an hour, the first station would be half an hour further